# This server is in the failed servers list (failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

While connecting from local machine Java Program to the Hbase server's zookeeper we are getting following error

> failed on local exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: ***This server is in
>   the failed servers list:*** *****/*******:16020"

though its connecting fine server.

**What I have done so far:**

> I have tried restarting zookeeper / base / master / region servers.

connectivity through UI is not a problem ****:16010/master-status.

> *I am managing Hbase through ambari*

---

**full log here:**

```
java.io.IOException: Call to *****/*******:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: *****/*******:16020

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.getTableState(MetaTableAccessor.java:1076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getTableState(ConnectionImplementation.java:1949)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.isTableDisabled(ConnectionImplementation.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:105)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Call to *****/*******:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: *****/*******:16020
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.wrapException(IPCUtil.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$200(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.get(ClientProtos.java:42510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientServiceCallable.doGet(ClientServiceCallable.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$1.rpcCall(HTable.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$1.rpcCall(HTable.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.call(RegionServerCallable.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:107)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: *****/*******:16020
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.getConnection(AbstractRpcClient.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:420)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

---

this question is not answered anywhere on any portal. I hope I will get some good answers.